# StandartScaler.inverse_transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I use StandardScaler to scale the data before feeding it into the model. After training I am trying to get a prediction (forecast of 250 time steps for 36 days), that is, in my test set there are 250 data points and I make a forecast of each for 36 days. I get forecasts this way with dimension (250, 36), which is what is expected:

```
predictions = []

with torch.no_grad():
    for test_x, test_y in patchtst_learner.test_dataloader:
        test_x = test_x.to("cuda")
        pred_y = patchtst_learner.model(test_x)
        predictions.extend(pred_y.cpu().numpy())
```

After receiving, I want to restore the original values ​​for these predictions, but I’m not successful... I don’t know how to get it correctly...

I have a class that splits data and scales, can you help me how can I return the original values ​​for predicitons:

```
class ETTDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset="OGD", mode="train", scale=True, seq_len=72, pred_len=36):
        super().__init__()
        df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/forecast/{}.csv".format(dataset))
        x_y = df.iloc[:, 1:]
        time_stamp = df.iloc[:, 0]

        assert mode in ['train', 'test', 'val']
        type_map = {'train': 0, 'val': 1, 'test': 2}
        self.set_type = type_map[mode]

        self.seq_len = seq_len
        self.pred_len = pred_len

        # Новые границы для seq_len и pred_len
        border1s = [0, 1659, 2017]
        border2s = [1658, 2016, 2374]
        border1 = border1s[self.set_type]
        border2 = border2s[self.set_type]

        # Сохранение исходных данных до масштабирования
        if not scale:
            self.original_data_x = x_y.to_numpy(dtype=np.float32)
            self.original_time_stamp = time_stamp.to_numpy()
            
        if scale:
            train_x_y = x_y.iloc[border1s[0]: border2s[0]]
            self.ss = StandardScaler()
            self.ss.fit(train_x_y.to_numpy(dtype=np.float32))
            x_y = self.ss.transform(x_y.to_numpy(dtype=np.float32))
        else:
            x_y = x_y.to_numpy(dtype=np.float32)

        time_stamp = time_stamp.to_numpy()

        self.data_x = x_y[border1: border2, :]
        self.data_y = x_y[border1: border2, -1]

        self.data_stamp = time_stamp[border1: border2]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        s_begin = index
        s_end = s_begin + self.seq_len
        r_begin = s_end
        r_end = r_begin + self.pred_len

        seq_x = self.data_x[s_begin:s_end]
        seq_y = self.data_y[r_begin:r_end]
        return seq_x, seq_y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_x) - self.seq_len - self.pred_len + 1

    def inverse_transform(self, data):
        return self.ss.inverse_transform(data)
```